# Can't create any xml file in any directory

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

In Android Studio I switched from Android to Packages to see all the directories, but since then I can't create any new directory or file.

I am getting this error in the upper corner https://i.imgsafe.org/d30a87bd97.jpg

The only way to create new directory is from the folder to manually add new folder but even then I can't create any file. I try with creating new xml but nothing happens.

Someone had this issue?

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

What do you see on the left side of the screen? You can try restarting it as I am sure you have done. If not you can restore the layout to its default settings by going to WINDOW->Restore Default Layout.

Comment: Tried, doesn't help.

Comment: Can you post an image of the entire IDE?

Comment: Hi, I have nothing changed. It returns this error :  NullPointerException: null .

Here is picture https://i.imgsafe.org/d3dc378428.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I would say uninstalling it and reinstalling it.